# Where a redirect is coming from?

Tags: redirect, mobile-website, tracking

I am making a website, where a person could be redirected to a form page several different pages within the site and depending on where they were redirected from, the form would be filled out certain to make it quick for them. This is all on the mobile, so data has to be kept in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is usually contained in the [HTTP `Referer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) header field.

Comment: I did a little research on that, but I could find away to access that information. Do have you link or something that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Only if you provide more context. What programming language are you using? What relevant framework(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this data from the headers sent by the browser (referrer URL) - usually these are stored as "Server variables"

However, I would recommend staying clear of this method as it can introduce a few other problems. I would recommend using session/cookies to keep track of the last page the user has visited.